# Listen to page refresh and window close on react-router

Tags: reactjs, location, react-router, refresh, history

It seems like the `<Prompt>` component from `react-router` only listens to `history.block` which only acts when the URL is changed.

I want to display the same `<Prompt>` component when user refreshes (F5) or close the window. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can prevent page refresh via JS:

```
PromptComponent extends Component {      

  // Add a listener to prevent browser page refresh
  componentWillMount() {
    onbeforeunload = e => "Don't leave"
  }

  // Clear listener
  componentWillUnmount() {
    onbeforeunload = null
  }
}
```

Check out here: [ONLINE](https://codesandbox.io/s/xl7xkv5q3p)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I don't want to just detect when user refreshes or leaves the page, but show the `<Prompt>` component when that happens.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but it still seems to get some traffic

```
  getSnapshotBeforeUpdate() {
    if (this.navigationPrompt()) {
      window.onbeforeunload = () => true
    } else {
      window.onbeforeunload = null
    }
    return null
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    onbeforeunload = null
  }
```

is my solution so far, but it shows to default warning -- I'll updated if I figure out how to show my prompt

Note:

`this.navigationPrompt()` is the same logic controller I use in my prompt:

```
  <Prompt
    when={this.navigationPrompt()}
    message="It looks like you haven't sent your email, are you sure you want to leave?"
  />
```